# Veracrypt hidden volume option disabled

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, veracrypt

I'm trying to have veracrypt create a hidden system volume on my PC. I have only 1 disc (SSD 256gb), it's win 10 home. When I run VC it works like a charm in all instances, but the option to encrypt the system only gives me the option of "normal", the option to make it hidden is disabled (greyed out). What am I doing wrong? In my view a hidden volume is almost always the way to go.

Comment: No one can help out on this one?